# Emscripten linker couldn't find functions, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, emscripten, gyp

Suppose I have function abc implemented module.cc and I build module.o and then link with flag:

```
-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_abc']"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
WARNING  root: function requested to be exported, but not implemented: "_abc"
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

enclosing the functions within `extern "C" {}` fixed the issue.